# swift: Загрузка нескольких файлов

Tags: ios, swift

Нужно скачать 10 файлов с показом прогресса загрузки для всех 10 файлов после нажатия на любую ячейку таблицы. Каждой ячейке соответствует свой файл( `cell1 - file1`, `cell2 - file2` и т.д ). Все 10 файлов загружаются нормально. Проблема в том, что прогресс загрузки отображается только в нажатой ячейке для одного файла. А нужно чтобы прогресс отображался во всех ячейка для соответствующих им файлов. Как это сделать?

Этот код использую для загрузки файлов:

```
     override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        for index in 1...10 {
            let url = URL(string: "link\(index)")!
            let downloadTasks = backgroundSession.downloadTask(with: url)
            downloadTasks.resume()

            let progressView = progressViews(frame: CGRect(x: CGFloat(0), y: CGFloat(0), width: CGFloat(24), height: CGFloat(24)))
            let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)
            cell?.accessoryView = progressViews
            progressView.startprogressView()
        }}
```

Comment: Вызвать этот же самый код 10 раз, только меняя URL?

Comment: @RomanPodymov например `for index1 in 1…10 `?

Comment: А в чём проблема-то собственно? Быть может у Вас есть какое-то табличное представление данных и Вы не можете при нажатии на определённую ячейку загрузить связанный с ней файл? Или в чём дело?

Comment: @RomanPodymov Добавил новый код в вопрос(**UPD**).  10 файлов загружаются, но из-за `let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)` Прогресс отображается только в выбранной ячейке. А нужно чтобы прогресс был в каждой из 10 ячеек. Можно ли это реализовать в `didSelectRowAt indexPath` или нужно создать новую функцию?

Comment: Стоп, Вы же уже что-то подобное спрашивали https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/645377/swift-Загрузка-нескольких-файлов-одновременно/645572#645572 и https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/646059/swift-загрузка-нескольких-файлов-с-показом-прогресса . Чем Вас не устроил ответ? Или сейчас проблема в другом?

Comment: @RomanPodymov Те ответы меня полностью устроили, но сейчас проблема в другом. И было бы не совсем правильно обсуждать разные проблемы по 1 теме в одном и том же вопросе.  И Я описал проблему комментарием выше.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57392/discussion-between-roman-podymov-and-user).

Comment: @RomanPodymov Вы правильно поняли идею. В чате писать не могу.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В принципе у Вас уже всё готово для решения поставленной Вами задачи, Вы лишь забываете правильно указать ячейку, у которой надо показывать загрузку. Кроме этого, самым лучшим вариантом для Вас будет сохранять индексы необходимых ячеек в какую-нибудь переменную, а зачем при перерисовке из неё извлекать значения (если бы у Вас гарантированно все элементы всегда были бы видимы, то можно было бы решить все проблемы проще). Итак, создаёте такое член-данное у себя в классе:

```
private var cellsIndexesForLoaing = [Int]()
```

При нажатии на ячейку инициализируйте данную переменную нужным диапазоном:

```
public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    self.cellsIndexesForLoaing = [Int](0..<10)
    self.table.reloadData() // И не забудьте обновить саму таблицу
}
```

Затем при перерисовке каждой ячейки проверяйте, надо ли начинать загрузку соответствующего файла:

```
public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = table.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Идентификатор Вашей ячейки", for: indexPath)
    let indexOfCell = self.cellsIndexesForLoaing.index(of: indexPath.row)
    if (indexOfCell != nil) { // Если текущая ячейка попала в диапазон, то начинаем загрузку

        loadFileWithProgress(index: indexPath.row, cell: cell) // Функция для загрузки файлов
        self.cellsIndexesForLoaing.remove(at: indexOfCell!) // Если мы начали загрузку, то текущую ячейку можно смело удалять из диапазона
    } else {

        //Так как ячейки таблицы кешируются и повторно используются, то Вам нужно ещё и вернуть ячейку к первоначальному состоянию (например, просто удалить её accessoryView, а можете ещё и загрузку прервать)  
        cell.accessoryView = nil
    }
    return cell
}
```

Функция для загрузки файла может выглядеть так:

```
func loadFileWithProgress(index:Int, cell:UITableViewCell) {

        let url = URL(string: "link\(index)")!
        //let downloadTasks = backgroundSession.downloadTask(with: url)
        //downloadTasks.resume()

        let progressView = UIView.init(frame: CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 0, width: 20, height: 20))
        //let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)
        progressView.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
        cell.accessoryView = progressView
        //progressView.startprogressView()
    }
```

В ней я закомментировал всё лишнее и ради примера устанавливаю в качестве `accessoryView` обычный чёрный прямоугольник.

Весь код в ответе написан на Swift 3.3.

Comment: Если добавляю свой код в Вашу функцию то приложение постоянно пытается загрузить одну ссылку, а потом вылетает.

Comment: @user Интересно узнать, как именно Вы добавили Ваш код в мою функцию? Я же Вам предоставил в принципе уже готовую функцию, Вы её пробовали вызывать из Вашего обработчика кнопки?

Comment: Моя кнопка это сама ячейка, по нажатию на ячейку должна стартовать загрузка.

Comment: @user В таком случае у вас конечно же будет переполнение стека. Тогда Вам нужно сам механизм загрузки вынести в отдельную функции и вызывать его вместо didSelectRowAt:.

Comment: пытался это сделать, но возникла проблема с `let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)`. Мне нужно показать `progressView` в каждой из 10 ячеек как `cell?.accessoryView`. Как это сделать в отдельной функции? В этом-то основной вопрос.

Comment: @user Рекомендую Вам поправить код в вопросе, а то Вы туда такого понагородили, что не совсем понятно, что вы запускаете и какая появляется проблема.

Comment: Обновил вопрос.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57457/discussion-between-roman-podymov-and-user).

Comment: Работает, только есть проблема. Если ячейка находится не в области экрана(ячейки 9,10 не попадают на экран, нужно проскроллить чтобы увидеть их) То `progressView` не отображается и не показывает прогресс.

Comment: @user Исправил свой ответ. Суть в том, что если ячейки не видно, то  она может быть ещё пока не создана, и cellForRow будет возвращать тогда нулевое значение. Попробуйте заменить на dequeueReusableCell.

Comment: Изменил. Теперь анимация прогресса появляется только в выделенной ячейке и в тех, которые создаются при скроллинге.

Comment: @user Обновил ответ.

Comment: @user Обновил ответ, надеюсь теперь Вы его примите.

Comment: Код в предыдущем редактировании Вашего ответа работает, если добавить `self.tableView.reloadData()` после `progressView.startprogressView()` так ведь проще?

Comment: @user Выберите сами для себя более подходящий вариант, но лично я бы выбрал своё текущее решение.

Comment: А чем текущий вариант лучше?

Comment: @user По-моему более надёжный, но если не сможете его внедрить, то используйте то, что было раньше.

Answer (score 1):

**Не минусуйте!** Пишу в ответ так как **в комменты смогу писать** когда **рейт** будет **> 50**.

Советую описать вашу проблему более детально, потому что навскидку вижу минимум два направления решения - например:

1) Если вам нужно загрузить изображение, то вероятнее всего вам подойдёт какая-то сторонняя библиотека типа SDWebImage, где в функции прогресс это аргумент. Которая вдобавок кеширует полученные данные и гарантирует отсутствие двойной/повторной загрузки. Да, есть библиотеки просто для загрузки - Alamofire всякие.

2) Решение должно использовать только нативный код - классы предоставленный Apple, a не сторонние библиотеки

А что касательно вашего кода, то в нём видимо нужно конформить протокол URLSessionTaskDelegate, а именно  и указать как делегат ваш класс

Вот этот [ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23987813/4742680) содержит код на Objective-C, который как минимум покажет в какую сторону копать. Удачи!

Comment: Минусовать не буду, коль уж просите, но мне кажется, что автору надо скачивать что-то увесистое (например, видео, оттого и необходимость показывать прогресс), и SDWebImage здесь точно не обойтись.

Comment: Вы так ответили как будто я в ответе ереси наговорил : )

Comment: Ни в коем случае не хотел Вас обидеть, просто раз уж Вы попросили не минусовать, то я и не минусую (то есть если это кто-то и сделает, то им буду не я). Вообще ответ у Вас довольно толковый, но @user нужна более конкретная помощь.

Comment: понимаю, поэтому и написал всё что идёт после фразы "Советую описать вашу проблему более детально". Если бы писал в коменты, то я бы этим и ограничился. в общем рад что вы меня услышали, успехов вам и автору! : )